# How to assign Ownerid to queue?

Tags: apex, soql

```
Group s =    [select Id from Group where Name = 'HC' AND Type = 'Queue'];
System.debug('s is ---->'+s);
list<QueueSobject> q = [select Id, QueueId from QueueSobject WHERE SobjectType = 'Lead' AND Queue.Name ='HC'];
system.debug('q is '+q);
newopp.ownerId = q[0].QueueId;
```

> error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Owner ID: id value of incorrect
>   type: 00G28000002c5nxEAA: [OwnerId]

Answer (score 1):

Confirm you can make Queue as an owner of this records because in some case you can't make Queue as a owner. With your variable name `newopp` I think you are doing it for Opportunity. Unfortunately you can't make a queue Opportunity owner. Only user can be opportunity owner.

[image]

**Update**

This is a known limitation of salesforce. I just did some research and found that already an Idea has been raised to Salesforce. Details can be found [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DfoWAAS)

Comment: yeah I think so we cannot do that for opportunity thats why I am getting constant error

Comment: @avidForce yes for Opportunity it is not supported.